# remoteapp not started from rdp file on windows 2008 R2

Tags: rdp, remoteapp

Server: Windows 2008 R2, myProgram.exe installed as remoteapp with alias "myProgram"

Client: Windows 2008 R2

rdp file in use:

```
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:1
redirectsmartcards:i:1
devicestoredirect:s:*
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectdrives:i:1
session bpp:i:32
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
server port:i:3389
allow font smoothing:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:1
authentication level:i:2
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
gatewaycredentialssource:i:0
full address:s:10.0.30.58
alternate shell:s:||myProgram
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||myProgram
gatewayhostname:s:
remoteapplicationname:s:myProgram.exe
```

symptom: after inputting credential a blank window is hanging there without remoteapp being launched.

There is event 9003 reported from event log, however there is no theme enabled on both machines.

Then after juggling with various rdp settings finally only when `remoteapplicationmode` is set to 0, it can start though in desktop mode. Problem is how to get it working in intended remoteapp mode (this param set to 1), please advise.